# With GRE not being accepted or being considered optional due to Covid, which other aspects of application will be given heavier weightage?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre, covid-19

Due to COVID-19 many universities (at least many Physics departments) are not accepting or are considering the GRE as optional. So, which other aspects of my application might be given heavier weightage? Of course, I'll mail individual departments and check with them. However, any suggestions here will be helpful in planning my path.

Comment: I don't know physics, but the general view in my fields was that the GRE was the lowest thing on the list anyway.

Answer (score 3):

All of them, proportionately.

PhD admissions in the US (the land of the GRE) are typically not based on a formula.  They are subjective.  Therefore you do not need to know how different parts of the application are weighted.